# foreach multiple arrays and group values determined by an ID value on each array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to use the foreach loop to loop over multiple arrays and separate values into 2 groups determined by an ID value on each array and then echo them, eventually to a table.

So for example I have the given 2D array as follows: (I have used just 3 as an example but there will be more in reality)

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (

            [numbpeople] => 3
            [people] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => bert
                            [mainId] => 2
                            [beens] => 0
                            [coins] => 8
                            [total] => 3
                            [ammount] => 2
                            [place] => 15
                            [type] => 0

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => bungle
                            [mainId] => 1
                            [beens] => 0
                            [coins] => 4
                            [total] => 0
                            [ammount] => 10
                            [place] => 13
                            [type] => 0

                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => fred
                            [mainId] => 2
                            [beens] => 0
                            [coins] => 3
                            [total] => 1
                            [ammount] => 8
                            [place] => 11
                            [type] => 0

                        )

                  )

            )

      )
```

I try the following code but it does not work the way its intended.

```
//foreach ($data['results']['people'] as $pValue) {
foreach ($data['results']['people'] as $Key => $pValue) {
$numPeople = $data["results"]["numbpeople"]; //[$i];

    if($numPeople>-1)
    {
        $MainId1="";
        $MainId2="";

        // set up header
        echo "<strong>People:<br>name, beens, coins, total.</strong><br>";
        echo "<br>";

        // calculate who's got what?
        $i=0;       
        while($i<$numPeople)
        {
                $pname[$i]=$pValue["name"][$i];
                $pmainId[$i]=$pValue["mainId"][$i];
                $pbeens[$i]=$pValue["beens"][$i];
                $pcoins[$i]=$pValue["coins"][$i];
                $ptotal[$i]=$pValue["total"][$i];
                if(!stristr($pValue["mainId"],"1") && !stristr($pValue["mainId"],"2")) {


                    if($pmainId[$i]!=$MainId1 && $MainId1=="") {
                        $p1Name=$pname[$i];         // people1 name
                        $p1Beens=$pbeens[$i];       // people1 beens
                        $p1Coins=$pcoins[$i];       // people1 coins
                        $p1Total=$ptotal[$i];       // people1 total
                    }
                    if($pmainId[$i]!=$MainId1 && $MainId1!="" && $MainId2=="") {
                        $p2Name=$pname[$i];         // people2 name
                        $p2Beens=$pbeens[$i];       // people2 beens
                        $p2Coins=$pcoins[$i];       // people2 coins
                        $p2Total=$ptotal[$i];       // people2 total
                    }   

                    // Id
                    if($pmainId[$i]!=$MainId1 && $MainId1=="") {
                        $MainId1=$pmainId[$i];
                    }
                    if($pmainId[$i]!=$MainId1 && $MainId1!="" && $MainId2=="") {
                        $MainId2=$pmainId[$i];
                    }       
                } else {
                    $MainId1="1";
                    $MainId2="2";
                }

            // output people ?

                echo $i.". -> ".$p1Name[$i].", ".$p1Beens[$i].", ".$p1Coins[$i].", ".$p1Total[$i];
                //    1            bungle             0                 4                 0
                echo "<br>";
                echo $i.". -> ".$p2Name[$i].", ".$p2Beens[$i].", ".$p2Coins[$i].", ".$p2Total[$i];
                //    1             bert              0                 8                 3
                //    2             fred              0                 3                 1
                echo "<br>";
                echo $MainId1, $MainId2;
                //       1         2
                echo "<br>";


            $i++;
        }

                }else   {

                echo "No people";
        }
    }
```

A better more refined solution would be very helpful.

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: Please provide the data structure that you want to get as output for the sample input you have given. NB: it is strange to see in the sample input `numbpeople` is 2 when an array of three entries follows. What is the meaning of that difference?

Comment: sorry typo corrected now

Answer (score 0):

Some advices after looking on code:

- Prepare data before sending it to view
- Next try to separate logic from view

My answer shows how array can be separeted in arrays by id:

```
$people=$results["results"]["people"];
$result=[];
$count=count($people);// i don't need special numbpeople in array

for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){

  $id=$people[$i]['mainId'];

  if (!isset($result[$id]))
  $result[$id]=[];//create new array for this id

  $result[$id][]=$people[$i]; //add people to this collection

}
```

After above loop in results we have this structure:

```
[ 
1 => [ [peopley],[peoplex] ]
2 => [ [peoplez],[peoplew] ]
....
]
```

This structure is grouped by mainId.

How to show people from above structure:

```
$size=count($result)
for ($i=0;$i<$size; $i++){

    //loop on groups

    $peoples=$result[$i];//array with people in this group
    $groupSize=count($peoples);

    for ($j=0;$j<$groupSize; $j++){

      //loop in group
      echo $peoples[$j]["name"];//example show name
    }
}
```

Comment: @Renny i wroted code here, not tested it, i forgotten to close ). Code fixed. Check it.

Comment: This is standard php array $arr=[] is the same like $arr=array(); If You have syntax error change it to array(), but You must have very old PHP.

Comment: Yes it can be something else it is only example variable name